# Accessing existing resource info from new resources

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

My header might not have summed up correctly my question.

So I have a terraform stack that creates a resource group, and a keyvault, amongst other things. This has already been ran and the resources exist.

I am now adding another resource to this same terraform stack. Namely a mysql server. Now I know if I just re-run the stack it will check the state file and just add my mysql server.

However as part of this mysql server creation I am providing a password and I want to write this password to the keyvault that already exists.

if I was doing this from the start my terraform would look like:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sqlpassword" {
    name         = "flagr-mysql-password"
    value        = random_password.sqlpassword.result
    key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.shared_kv.id
    depends_on   = [
      azurerm_key_vault.shared_kv
    ]
}
```

however I believe as the keyvault already exists this would error as it wouldn't know this value azurerm_key_vault.shared_kv.id unless I destroy the keyvault and allow terraform to recreate it. is that correct?

I could replace azurerm_key_vault.shared_kv.id with the actual resource ID from azure, but then if I were to ever run this stack to create a new environment it would be writing the value into my old keyvault I presume?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently for AWS deployment, you would do `terraform import` on  `azurerm_key_vault.shared_kv` resource to bring it under terraform management and then you would be able to able to deploy `azurerm_key_vault_secret`

To import: you will need to build the resource `azurerm_key_vault.shared_kv` (this will require a few iterations).